# How To Pass in or Set Environment Variable for Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script as part of Azure DevOps pipeline.  I also want to run it from windows command line.  How can I set them before calling them in windows?  Perhaps in a cmd file?  Note - these are temporary for a single execution and don't want to set windows environment variables.

I am accessing the environment variables like this in the powershell script:

```
$tfsAccessToken = If ($serverMode) {$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN} else {"somethingelse"}
$tfsBuildDefinitionId = If ($serverMode) {$env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID} else {2}
```

Comment: Do you want to set in PowerShell a variable that will be available in the next CMD task (in azure devops)?

Comment: no, answer below is what i want to do. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SET` command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html):

> Display, set, or remove *CMD* environment variables. Changes made
>   with `SET` will remain only for the duration of the **current *CMD*
>   session**.

**Example**.

Supposedly, the `_foo` environment variable isn't defined in a newly opened *CMD* prompt:

```
set _foo
```

> ```
> Environment variable _foo not defined
> ```

```
powershell -nologo -noprofile -command "& {$env:_foo ; $null -eq $env:_foo}"
```

> ```
> True
> ```

However, if defined, the `_foo` environment variable is visible in the child process `powershell`:

```
set "_foo=bar"
powershell -nologo -noprofile -command "& {$env:_foo ; $null -eq $env:_foo}"
```

> ```
> bar
> False
> ```

Another example (asynchronous child process `powershell`):

```
set "_foo=bar"
start "SO_57237835" powershell -noexit -nologo -noprofile -command "& {$env:_foo;$null -eq $env:_foo}"
```

[image: SO_57237835]